# How to show current git branch in Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Is there a plugin or some setting in EGit to show the current git branch in the toolbar of eclipse so that it's visible on which branch you're working?

Comment: I don't think there is any such setting because there could be multiple repositories in a workspace, but the Git Repositories view shows the active branch against each repository, if that is of any help to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like [Sasikanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3682857/sasikanth-bharadwaj) says there is no toolbar in EGit that shows the current branch.

Since there usually are multiple repositories within your IDE, a toolbar that shows the current branch of a single repository would probably often choose the wrong repository to display.

But if you have an idea how such a toolbar could work you may want to [open an enhancement request](https://eclipse.org/egit/support/).

In the meanwhile you can either use the *Repositories View* to see the current branch of each repsoitory or look at the *Pakckage Explorer* or *Project Explorer*. The projects are decorated with the repository they belong to and the current branch that is checked out.

[image: Package Explorer showing EGit decorations]

Here the project belongs to the `gitexample` repository on branch `master`.